# Fechar o modal Bootstrap após efetuar o cadastro

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Colegas

Tenho um sistema do qual o usuário ao clicar no link **Cadastrar Matéria** abrirá o modal abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém gostaria que ao clicar em **Salvar**, o modal fechasse automaticamente. Tentei usar o código abaixo, o modal fecha, mas o fundo permanece:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('#submit').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $("#myModal").hide();
    });
});
```

O fundo permanece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente `$("#myModal").modal("hide");` (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

subtitua:

```
 $("#myModal").hide();
```

por:

```
$("#myModal").modal('hide');
```

Se não me engano é isso

Comment: Estava escrevendo isso agora...rs `+1`

Comment: Perfeito Cassiano. Funcionou. Só posso aceitar sua resposta após 11 minutos, mas voltarei aqui pra aceitar. Obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Fox.11 . Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Tive um problema semelhante, porém em um projeto onde estava utilizando AngularJS.

então quando o usuário clicasse em salvar, executava a seguinte função:

```
vm.modalFecha = function(){
    $('#modalpesq').modal('hide');
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('display', 'none');
    $('.ng-scope').removeClass('modal-open');
}
```

Acredito que somente inserindo a linha abaixo já resolva o seu problema:

```
$('.modal-backdrop').css('display', 'none');
```